# How can I answer a Rishon's question

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rishonim

Since the Rishonim are a lot greater than us, and most of them had ruach hakodesh (see chabadlibrary.org/books/bsht/kst/3/217.htm), would it be possible for me to think of an answer to a question that the Rishonim couldn't think of? Or would that have to mean that my answer is wrong for some reason?

Comment: the working assumption of most people who learn Rishonim is to ask it as a question - "Why didn't the Rishon answer like this or that?" and then try and figure out what is wrong with it. Usually, there is a different Rishon or earlier Achron who will give that answer and it is based on a machlokes how to understand a specific point. If nobody at all gives your answer, then chances are you are mistaken somehow, since it is around 700 years worth of seforim written, that came across this topic, and to say NONE of them thought of it besides for you is a bit preposterous

Comment: The best way to think about this is in the context of the story related in the Talmud, Menachot 29b which relates how Moshe Rabbeinu, the one who transmitted the entire Torah, oral and written, to us was shown Rabbi Akiva teaching Torah to his students. It explains that Moshe Rabbeinu did not understand what  Rabbi Akiva was teaching. Take note of Rashi's comments there.

Comment: "would it be possible" Since the Rishonim are a not infinitely greater than us, then of course it's possible. It may be rare, but surely possible. I don't understand what's confusing here.

Comment: Just curious - what is the source that most Rishonim had Ruach Hakodesh?

Comment: Do you mean, how can you answer a rishon's question where the rishon bleibs schwer. Or do you mean how can you give an alternative answer to the rishon's question.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות My elementary school teachers?

Comment: I found this from Rabbi soloveithick on https://www.torahweb.org/torah/special/2019/ryds_rietsalumni.html

Comment: "The truth can be discovered only through joining the ranks of the chochmei hamasora. It is ridiculous to say, "I have discovered something of which the Rashba didn't know, the Ketzos didn't know, the Vilna Gaon had no knowledge. I have discovered an approach to the interpretation of Torah that is completely new." It is ridiculous. One has to join the ranks of the chochmei hamasora - Chazal, Rishonim, gedolei Acharonim."

Comment: @רבותמחשבות It is brought down in the Sefer Keser Shem Tov (hosofos 217) in the name of the Baal Shem Tov. The link to see it is https://chabadlibrary.org/books/bsht/kst/3/217.htm

Comment: @MoisheFishoff I know your question didn't deal with this, but in matters where we have access to either better manuscripts or better science it's not even a question that we can know more things than the Rashba Ketzos or Vilna Gaon. You're only asking about places where they and we had full access to the relevant base data.

Comment: @moishe thank you so much!

Comment: As an example of @DoubleAA's point, the [Leshem](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37426&st=&pgnum=159&hilite=) says that the Rambam only pursued his philosophy (inappropriately so, he says, but it was at least l'sheim shamayim) because Chochmas Hakabbalah was not revealed yet. In our generation, however, now that Chochmas Hakabbalah has been revealed (and has been since the time of the Arizal), we have no right to pursue those philosophical angles.

Comment: @Yehuda On the flip side of that, many of late rishonim who believed Rashbi wrote the full literal Zohar text probably didn't know all the historical anachronisms that would entail. As you see these arguments can often be used both ways.

Answer (score 7):

> "Rabbi Yehoshua ben Zeruz, son of the father-in-law of Rabbi Meir, testified before Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi about Rabbi Meir that he ate the leaf of a vegetable in Beit She’an without tithing or separating teruma, as he holds that Beit She’an is not part of Eretz Yisrael and therefore is not sacred with its sanctity. And Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi permitted all the produce of Beit She’an on the basis of his testimony.
>
> His brothers and his father’s household united against him and said to him: In a place where your fathers and the fathers of your fathers treated untithed produce as forbidden, will you treat it as permitted?
>
> Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi interpreted this verse to them: “And he broke in pieces the copper serpent that Moses had made; for until those days the children of Israel burned incense to it; and it was called Nehushtan” (II Kings 18:4). Is it possible that they burned incense to it and Asa, a righteous king, came and did not eradicate it, and Jehoshaphat, a righteous king, came and did not eradicate it, and it remained until the time of Hezekiah? But didn’t Asa and Jehoshaphat eradicate all objects of idol worship in the world?
>
> Rather, it must be that in not eradicating the serpent, his ancestors left Hezekiah room through which to achieve prominence. I too can say that my ancestors left me room through which to achieve prominence by permitting untithed produce from Beit She’an.
>
> The Gemara adds: From here one learns with regard to a Torah scholar who states a new matter of halakha that one does not move  him from his position; and some say: One does not disregard him; and some say: One does not attribute his innovative statement to his conceit."
>
> (Talmud Bavli Tractate Chulin 6b - 7a  ; Translation and paraphrase - Sefaria online)

G-d makes sure that no matter how great the previous generation of sages, room is left for You to be able to become a Torah student and achieve things that the previous sages did not achieve, because it is your mission and not theirs.

Just make sure that you learn Torah and follow the right path of study from real Rabbis and teachers. Eventually, yes, your own answers will be a guideline to understand why you are wrong, and then with further achievement you will be granted the power to come up with real answers, even to a Rishon's question.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to cite the *gemara* [David Kenner already did](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/127482/1570). But I wanted to add a codicil... This happens quite naturally. (The following is just logic from first principles. Don't fault me for not having sources; I was just beaten to the punch with my intended source.)

You aren't likely going to invent the cell phone until someone before you invent the telephone and someone else discovers radio waves and invents ways to harness it. And someone else comes up with Quantum Mechanics, the physics of semiconductors, and how to make chips so tiny. Someone else came up with Computer Science, algorithms, fast Fourier transforms (the math used to convert your sound waves to digital), etc, etc, etc...

The *Rishonim* were indeed brilliant. And more connected to Hashem and thus in tune with the Wisdom of His Torah. But it takes time until all the pieces of knowledge it takes to build to later conclusions accumulate. The *Rishonim* advanced the knowledge of Torah far more than we can. And less than Chazal did.

But without the pieces revealed to Moshe, uncovered by the *Zeqeinim*, *Anshei Keneses haGdolah*, *Chazal*, *Geonim*, *Rishonim*, and the *Acharonim* who came before us, things that seem obvious to us were jumps ahead of what was already revealed and known. It takes less genius as well as less Wisdom as they had to take pieces of the answer and put them together than to answer a question from scratch.

Comment: Are you quoting from someone or is that your own idea?

Comment: @MiZeh: me. Arguing from first principles. I guess whomever brought the "midgets atop the shoulders of giants can see farther than the giants" idea to Jewish discourse could have been given credit.

Comment: See Shu"t Rid Siman 62

אני דן בעצמי משל הפילוסופים שמעתי מחכמי הפילוסופים שאלו לגדול שבהם ואמרו לו הלא אנחנו מודים שהראשונים חכמו והשכילו יותר ממנו והלא אנחנו מודים שאנו מדברים עליהם וסותרים דבריהם בהרבה מקומות והאמת אתנו היאך יכון הדבר הזה השיבם אמר להם מי צופה למרחוק הננס או הענק הוי אומר הענק שעיניו עומדות במקום גבוה יותר מן הננס ואם תרכיב הננס על צוארי הענק מי צופה יותר למרחוק הוי אומר הננס שעיניו גבוהות עכשיו יותר מעיני הענק כך אנחנו ננסים רכובים על צוארי הענקים מפני שראינו חכמתם ואנו מעניקי' עליה ומכח חכמתם חכמנו לומר כל מה שאנו אומרים ולא שאנו גדולים מהם